# Accessing items in array shared using Laravel View::share

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I have this in my routes (only place it works...)

```
$constants = DB::table('constants')->get();
View::share('constants', $constants);
```

If in one of my views I var_dump constants I get this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#129 (3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["type"]=> string(13) "business_name" ["value"]=> string(17) "Project Framework" } }
```

I then want to do:

```
$business_name = $constants->business_name; 
or
$business_name = $constants['business_name'];
```

How can I manipulate my array from the DB call to be able to use the constants variable like this?

Is there a way in Laravel to do this simpler / more efficient than looping through in a foreach and creating the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have only one row in your `constants` you should use `first()` to retrieve a single record and not a collection:

```
$constants = DB::table('constants')->first();
```

Then you get a single object so you can use this notation to access the properties:

```
$business_name = $constants->business_name;
```

---

#### Edit

With your type-value structure I suggest using `lists`:

```
$constants = DB::table('constants')->lists('value', 'type');
```

This will create an array like this:

```
[
    'business_name' => 'Project Framework',
    'foo_type' => 'bar_value'
]
```

Usage

```
$business_name = $constants['business_name'];
```

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I didn't read it well enough.. Take a look at my updated answer

Comment: Perfect, never seen the lists item before. Thanks.